# Use opera OTransform to zoom out or scale out the webpage

Tags: javascript, css, transform, opera

I'm trying to zoom out my webpage when specified button clicked by the user, after going through many tutorials and stackoverflow questions I found ways to do so in FireFox, Chrome and Safari but those methods are not working in Opera but I found that it is possible to scale a webpage using `OTransform`.

I tried using `OTransform` but my coding just scale/zoom-in the webpage, is it possible to `zoom-out` the webpage using `OTransform` in Opera?

code

```
var zoom = 1.5;
document.body.style.OTransform = 'scale(' + zoom + ')';
```

I also tried using a negative value for `zoom` variable but its not working..

Comment: Okay guys, I found the way !! I hope this will help others who are tring to do so cuz I saw alot people looking for this.. if you need to zoom out the webpage to 90% just use 0.9 for zoom variable.

Comment: Post that as an answer yourself!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay guys, I found the answer myself just after posting this question!!

I hope this will help others who are trying to do so because I saw a lot people looking for this.. if you need to zoom out the webpage to 90% use `0.9` for `zoom` variable, 0.8 for 80% , 0.7 for 70% and so on . –

```
var zoom = 0.9;
document.body.style.OTransform = 'scale(' + zoom + ')';
```

Hope this would help someone... :)